# How to use sub query in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the result of multiple where condition with multiple LIKE clause .I tried with this below query :

```
 select * from  ALL_Post where ActiveStatus = '1' AND Status = 'PENDING' AND inspectorName LIKE '%"+searchText+"%' OR REMARK  LIKE '%"+searchText+"%' OR HashTag LIKE '%"+searchText+"%' ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

But i want to get result when at least any of the the conditions is true with where ActiveStatus = '1' AND Status = 'PENDING' with LIKE clause with OR clause.

But query not return proper result.Can someone suggest how to write above proper query.

Comment: take a logic course ... then you will know that you should use brackets ... `p1 & p2 & p3 & .... & pn | true` is always true ...

Comment: @Selvin : If you don't want to help anyone then please also don't comment . You give me logic course and teach me logic.

Comment: in your case you should use `p1 & p2 & ... & pn & qo` and `qo` should  be definde as `q1 | q2 | q3` ... but obviously it **is not** `p1 & p2 & ... & pn & q1 | q2 | q3` **but** `p1 & p2 & ... & pn & (q1 | q2 | q3)`

Comment: btw ... i'm serious about course ... if you wana be programer you should at least know [Boolean algebra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) basics (among other math related stuff)

Comment: Sorry for my bad comment. I thought you are tont on me.Sorry once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops) documents the precedence of the AND and OR operators. To evaluate them in a different order, you must use parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_Post
WHERE ActiveStatus = '1'
  AND Status = 'PENDING'
  AND (inspectorName LIKE '%"+searchText+"%' OR
       REMARK        LIKE '%"+searchText+"%' OR
       HashTag       LIKE '%"+searchText+"%')
ORDER BY ActionDate DESC;
```